# What if objective function $Z$ is also in the constraints?

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research

What if objective function $Z$ is in the constraints? 
To construct the dual form for this problem? how do I approach to this problem?

---

Maximize      $\;\;\;\;\;\;\; z$

subject to    $$\;\;\;z - \sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{ij}x_i \leq 0 $$

$$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \sum_{i=1}^{m}x_i  = 1$$

$$ x_i \geq 0\;\;\;\;\; \forall i=1,...,m$$

---

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't change anything (and in the general case, $z$ appears in the constraints, since otherwise maximizing $z$ would be very easy).

Here, the dual problem is minimizing $z$ subject to the constraints $z - a_{i,j}y_j \geq 0$ and $\sum y_j \geq 1$, as you can see by taking the transpose of the matrix.

Comment: The constraint should instead be $\sum_j y_j = 1$ (there's also a constraint that $y\ge0$). Incidentally, this proves the Minimax Theorem for two-player zero-sum games.